# SSH Port mapping to access remote database

Tags: mysql, ssh, ssh-keys, portforwarding

I have a server running a web application that uses a mysql database. The database itself is not located on that server -- it's located on another server. The database server is not accessible from my location.

I'd like to use ssh port mapping so I can run `mysql` on my Mac laptop and connect to the database. I'm assuming this means I need to connect to my web application server using ssh and port forwarding.

It's like this:

My Mac -> Web Server -> Database Server

I'd like to run the mysql command on my macbook pro something like this:

```
mysql -u dbuser -hlocalhost -p
```

and then type in the mysql password.

Also, I connect to my web server using ssh keys.

Comment: As a note, [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com) supports SSH connections natively if you don't specifically need the `mysql` command-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this option to your SSH command line:

```
 -L 127.0.0.1:3306:IP_OF_SQL_SERVER:3306
```

You will have to use 127.0.0.1 in mysql's `-h` option ("localhost" means using Unix sockets locally), and you might want to *disable* compression in SSH, while *activating* it in mysql client with the `-C` option.